# Validating pom.xml conforms to standard

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin

How to validate automatically that Java project pom.xml conforms to some well defined pom.xml template?

Validation may include tag structure, specific tags presence and tags values validation.

The goal is to add pom.xml validation to CI processes of repository automatic creation.

Obvious way is parsing pom.xml and making sure it conforms to standards, but is there maven alternative way which accepts as input pom.xml template file and pom.xml to validate?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the maven-enforcer-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/). It doesn't work on the pom syntax itself, but on the logical model built from it (it might not be exactly what you asked for, but maybe it still suits your needs).

Comment: It also allows to write custom rules (besides the one it already has builtin), so if there is something missing, you can add it yourself.

Comment: The question is: What do you define standard? And furthermore what exactly do you mean by "validation" of tags?  If you want to force some special things yes the maven-enforcer-plugin would be the way...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking [Pedantic POM Enforcers](https://github.com/ferstl/pedantic-pom-enforcers) rules for [Maven Enforcer Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/).